# Relevance of parity argument of dipole selection rules

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For context I write once the matrix element relevant for dipole selection rules:
$$ \left < f|\vec{\epsilon}\cdot\vec{r}|i \right >$$

Reading about the dipole selection rules e.g. [here](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node422.html) it is often stated that using the Wigner-Eckart Theorem we find that the change of the orbital angular momentum is either $1$, $0$ or $-1$ $\Delta l=0,\pm1$. However by parity we must further restrict this result to $\Delta l=\pm 1$.

However, let's now consider a specific example. Let's assume $\vec{\epsilon}=\hat{e_z}$ such that our operator is proportional to the spherical harmonic $Y^0_1$. By the Wigner Eckart theorem I know that:
$$\langle l'm'|Y_1^0|lm\rangle \propto \langle10;lm|l'm'\rangle$$
For example, if I plug in explicit wavefunctions of the same parity e.g. $l=1$, $m=1$, $l'=1$ and $m'=1$ I have a non-vanishing amplitude! Shouldn't this amplitude vanish by parity? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

By writing the operator as $r$ you are implicitly considering a one electron atom, in which case the total orbital angular momentum $L$ and the single electron angular momentum $l$ are identical. In this case the parity rule does interact with the angular momentum rule. However in general the rule for total orbital angular momentum $L$ is$\Delta L=0,\pm1$.

The simplest example of an allowed $\Delta L=0$ transition is probably in the carbon spectrum. The carbon ground state is $1s^22s^22p^2{\,}^3P$ with even parity. There is a fully allowed transition to $1s^22s^22p3s{\,}^3P$ for which $\Delta l=1$ ($p\to s$) but $\Delta L=0$ and $\Delta S=0$. This occurs at 1657 nm. (There is fine structure splitting in both triplet terms, but it is quite small.)

Answer (score 0):

(Re-written the answer as I had misinterpreted the question).

With $Y_1^0$ you are only considering the linear polarisation term, so the first term in the expansion in the final equation of your link:

$$ \propto \langle \ell_n m_n | \ell_i 1 m_i 0 \rangle. $$

From [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients), the closest case you can get is:
$$ \langle L, M| \ell_{1},\ell_{2}, m_{1},m_{2}\rangle =\ \delta _{M,m_{1}+m_{2}} \cdot (\text{bunch of stuff}),$$
amd from your expression $M = m_n$, $m_1 = m_i$, $m_2 = 0$.

Choosing $m_1 = m_2 = 1$ as you are trying to do, would give:
$$ \langle 1, 1| 1, 1, 1,0\rangle =\ \delta _{0,1+0} \cdot (\text{bunch of stuff}) , $$
so the $\delta$ kills the whole thing and you get zero.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean. I picked $Y_1^0$ which should correspond to a specific polarized light if I'm not mistaken.

Regarding the parity: In the source I have given above they argue with the parity of the spherical functions: 
"We also know that the $Y_{1m}$ are odd under parity so the other two spherical harmonics must have opposite parity to each other implying that $l_n \neq l_i$"

Comment: @PaulWegmann you are right I am sorry, re-written the answer.